# Android Sign In test

Tags: php, android

I'm developing my first sign in following this [article](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_php_mysql.htm). I've read a couple of others but this one seems simple/intuitive enough for me, specially when I'll want to do something bigger than a sign in.

I had to make some changes to the PHP script that was used.

UPDATE I have two php scripts, this is the correct one, the last one was for _GET method.

```
<?php
$con=mysql_connect("...");//deleted for privacy
mysql_select_db("..");//deleted for privacy
if (!$con)
{
   echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysql_error();
   die();
}
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

$query=mysql_query("SELECT username FROM users");
echo $query;echo $query;echo $query;echo $query;
if($query){
    $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query);
    $data = $row['username'];
    echo $data;
}else{
    echo "something went wrong:".mysql_error();
}
mysql_close($con);
?>
```

In any case I don't think the error is in the PHP, as I run the script on my browser using appropriate values in the URL for username/password and it prints out the response I'm looking for (which is just the username).
Here is my modified SignInActivity.

```
package com.example.phpmysql;
   public class LogInBackgroundActivity  extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>{
   private Context context;
   public AsyncResponse delegate=null; 
   public LogInBackgroundActivity(Context context) {
      this.context=context;
   }
   @Override
   protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
      String address ="...";//hidden for privacy
     try{
        String username = (String)arg0[0];
        String password = (String)arg0[1];
        address+="login_post.php";
        String data  = URLEncoder.encode("username", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(username, "UTF-8");
        data += "&" + URLEncoder.encode("password", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(password, "UTF-8");
        URL url = new URL(address);
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection(); 
        conn.setDoOutput(true); 
        OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream()); 
        wr.write( data ); 
        wr.flush(); 
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new     InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream()));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        // Read Server Response
        while((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
           sb.append(line);
           break;
        }
        return sb.toString();
     }catch(Exception e){
        return new String("Exception: " + e.getMessage());
     }
  }   
   @Override
   protected void onPostExecute(String result){

       if(result.length()>0)
      delegate.processFinished(result);
       else
           delegate.processFinished("Something Odd");
   }
}
```

What I understood from the tutorial is that everything that is printed on the php script get sent back with `onPostExecute(..)`. AsyncResponse is just an interface I created for transporting this data back to the main activity, according to this [question](https://www.google.com.pr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCkQFjAA&url=https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12575068/how-to-get-the-result-of-onpostexecute-to-main-activity-because-asynctask-is-a&ei=_M7uUseIA-y0sATHuYHIDw&usg=AFQjCNF3P7T4pqoUOvTT2KzoyQGNBU8KFQ&sig2=AeuLIA5K0QaWhFxeydP2dg).

This is the data that I want and it comes back empty.

I'm testing on a real device so I have no logcat reporting.

Answer (score 0):

I used `mysqli_*`, as it is used in the tutorial, and that seems to have solved the issue.